# When are Weighted $\mathcal{L}^p$-Spaces Topologically Isomorphic?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mu$ be the Borel measure on $X$. Suppose $W_1$ and $W_2$ are continuous, non-negative functions from $X$ into the real numbers such that, for all integers $p > 0$,
$$
\int_X W_i(x)\ d\mu(x) < +\infty, \ \ i = 1,2.
$$
Define the weighted $\mathcal{L}^p$-space $\mathcal{L}_W^p(X)$ as the space of measurable functions from $X$ to the reals for which the integral
$$
\left(\int_X f(x)^pW(x)\ d\mu(x)\right)^{1/p} 
$$
is finite. In this case the function $W$ is called the *weight function* for $\mathcal{L}_W^p$. Furthermore, it is well known that the integral above constitutes a norm on $\mathcal{L}^p_W(X)$. Under which conditions on the weight functions $W_1$ and $W_2$ are $\mathcal{L}_{W_1}^p(X)$ and $\mathcal{L}^p_{W_2}(X)$ topologically isomorphic? (i.e. when is there a Banach space isomorphism which is also a homeomorphism with respect to the norm-topologies due to the two weight functions?)

Comment: By "positive definite" do you mean non negative? If the weight functions are both strictly positive and finite, then the two weighted $L_p$ spaces are isometrically isomorphic via a multiplication operator.  This is easy and basic, so maybe you mean something else?

Comment: @BillJohnson Yes I meant non-negative. I am very much not an expert in this area, so the basic result eluded me. For the record, what would the operator be? Using the multiplier $W_1/W_2$ (or its inverse) would lead to problems in cases where $W(x) = 0$ for some $x$.

Comment: Note that @BillJohnson specified that he was talking about strictly positive weight functions.

Comment: @LSpice okay. Then yes, I agree this is a trivial case. Non-negativity is the key condition. We may **not** assume $W(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: How can you claim that these spaces are Banach if the functions $f$ are assumed continuous?

Comment: @RW I may have a terminology error. Please help me understand: why would continuous functions **not** form a Banach space? Is it a completeness issue?

Comment: Yes - if you only consider continuous functions your $L^p$ spaces won't be complete (unless $X$ is pretty exotic).

Comment: @RW OK. I believe changing the condition to measurable functions will solve this issue. Do you agree? What I was trying to communicate is the $f$ in this space are in some sense "nice enough".

Comment: Yes. Another question: are you asking about topological isomorphism (i.e., isomorphism of these $L^p$ spaces as topological spaces) or about Banach space isomorphism?

Comment: @RW I would like an isomorphism which is also a homeomorphism. This way both the algebraic and topological characters of the two spaces will agree. By Banach space isomorphism, I wanted to indicate nothing more than a linear bijection between the spaces, regarded as Banach spaces.

Comment: OK - is the following sufficient for your needs? If $X$ is not very big (say, separable, metriziable, complete) - then the $L^p$ spaces associated to all purely non-atomic  $\sigma$-finite measures on $X$ are isometrically isomorphic.

Comment: @RW I believe that's a fair restatement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space $L^p_W(X)$ is nothing else than the $L^p$ with respect to the finite measure $\mu_W$ whose density with respect to $\mu$ is $W$. Now you can use the fact that the measure spaces determined by purely non-atomic Borel probability measures on "nice" spaces $X$ (separable, metrizable, complete) are all isomorphic to the unit interval endowed with the Lebesgue measure, which implies that for any fixed $p$ the corresponding $L^p$ spaces are all isometrically isomorphic.